# Node js with mysql rest api GETTING Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT localhost

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest

Node js with mysql rest api GETTING  Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT localhost::

In mysql phpmyadmin i have creates database named job_portal with same username and password.

webapp.js :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = express("cors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

const dbService = require("./config/database");
const { response } = require("express");
//app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
//app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended : false }));

app.listen(process.env.app_port, () => { 
//console.log("server running....", process.env);
console.log("server running on port....", process.env.app_port);
});
```

database.js :

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config(); 
//const { response } = require("express");
//let instance = null;

const connection = mysql.createConnection({    
    host : process.env.host,
    user : process.env.user,
    password : process.env.password,
    database : process.env.database
});
console.log("process.env.db_port", process.env.user)
connection.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('db:: '+connection.state);
});
```

.env :

```
node_env = development
app_port = 5000
db_port = 3306
host = localhost
user = job_portal
password = job_portal
database = job_portal
connectionLimit = 10
```

Now facing error log:

```
process.env.db_port job_portal
server running on port.... 5000
Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT localhost
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\job portal in jquery\webservices\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\job portal in jquery\webservices\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\job portal in jquery\webservices\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\job portal in jquery\webservices\config\database.js:14:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  fatal: true
}
db:: disconnected
```

how should i fix this issue please help me to resolve

Comment: try `http://localhost` instead of `localhost`. Also I do not see where you have given the port for db connection. The host  should probably be `http://localhost:3306`

Comment: .env file contains host and port detail

Comment: Yes I know. But you haven't used the port while connecting with the database in `database.js`

Comment: I added port in js and tried http://localhost instead of localhost in env. It throwing same error

Comment: instead of localhost it requires address 127.0.0.1
thank you